# no able to post picture using forked twitter oauth by natefanaro

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

i am completely new to twitter api, and i dont know much about it. I want to create a program which tweets images from my website, which are selected by the visitor. So i need oauth and started using the oauthtwitter which is forked and is available here https://github.com/natefanaro/twitteroauth

which is said to have support to post images. But when i try to do it i dont get the images tweeted. I have all the permissions to write and read data in my app on twitter. Here is my code

```
if (empty($_SESSION['access_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'])) {
    header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
}
/* Get user access tokens out of the session. */
$access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];

/* Create a TwitterOauth object with consumer/user tokens. */
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);

/* If method is set change API call made. Test is called by default. */
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
$params = array(
    'status' => 'Testing API http://google.com',
    'media[]' => 'http://diit.cz/sites/default/files/google_chrome_logo.png'
);
// Send tweet
$status = $connection->upload('statuses/update_with_media', $params);
```

What is the problem here? Any help is appreciated